# Get the second on which the thumbnail was generated

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to generate thumbnails from a video every 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3 -i input.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4),scale=640:360" 
   -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/5 out%02d.jpg
```

The thumbnails generated are formatted using 2 digits. So images are generated starting from `out01.jpg`, `out02.jpg` and goes on until `out99.jpg`. Is there a way I could get the seconds in the filename? Like I want to know the number of seconds elapsed in the original video when any particular thumbnail was generated.

For example, it could be in a format resembling:

```
out01_23.jpg
out02_28.jpg
out03_33.jpg

.  
.
```

So here 23,28 and 33 represent the number of seconds elapsed in the video. `out01_33.jpg` is a thumbnail that represents the 33rd second of the video.

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='gte(t,3)*not(mod(t-3,5))' -frame_pts 1 fr\out%02d.jpg
```

Output filenames for a 30-fps video will be

```
out90.jpg
out240.jpg
out390.jpg
...
```

where 90 represents `90/30` == `3.00` seconds of the input; `240/30` == `8.00` seconds and so on.

Comment: This throws an error `Missing ')' or too many args in 'gte(t'`.

Comment: escape the commas e.g. `t,` -> `t\,`

Comment: Okay. How is this different from the command I had used earlier? I see that it misses a lot of parameters like `select=gt(scene\,0.4),scale=640:360` , `-vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/5`

Comment: Also. what happens if the video frame rate is not 30fps? Could you please explain

Comment: `-vf select='gte(t,3)*not(mod(t-3,5))'` picks a frame at seconds 3.0, 8.0, 13.0.. and so on. `-vsync 0` retains source timestamps, needed for your purpose. `-frame_pts 1` encodes the timestamp in the output filename.

Comment: If the fps is different, that only affects how you calculate the timestamp. Take `out90.jpg`, if source fps is 25, then 90 represents `90/25 = 3.6s`

Comment: In your original command, `-vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4),scale=640:360"` had no effect since it was replaced with another `-vf` later on. But what it would have done is selected all frames which were at least 40% different than the previous frame and then scaled them down to 640x360.